# NextJs crash caused by styled-components: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withConfig')

Tags: reactjs, next.js, babeljs, styled-components

I'm creating an npm package out of some CRA module which use styled-components and I use this npm package in a nextJs app which crashes because of styled components used by the npm package.

The npm code that uses styled-comp:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
export const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>`
  cursor: pointer;
  ...... `
```

package.json:

```
"babel": {
"presets": [
  "@babel/preset-typescript",
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "loose": true,
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 2 Chrome versions"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    {
      "runtime": "automatic"
    }
  ],
  "@lingui/babel-preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
  "babel-plugin-styled-components",
  "macros"      
]
```

}

Compiled code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
export const Button = styled.button.withConfig({
  displayName: "designSystem__Button",
  componentId: "sc-1symxt6-0"
 })(["cursor:pointer;color:", ";text-transform:capitalize;background-color:", ";box-sizing:border-box;padding:8px;border:2px solid
```

and the error:

```
typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'withConfig')
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@dude/web-plugins/dist/components/designSystem.js:8:70)
```

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this?